# Preventing cURL from resolving host to IP

Tags: curl

To save time I want to define what ip resolves from what host so curl doesn't have to waste time doing this itself (the IP will be static)

I just want confirmation from people more experienced with curl that the way I'm doing it will actually prevent curl from attempting to resolve the IP:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
struct curl_slist* chunk = NULL;
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk,"Host: website.com"); //(the website doesn't respond correctly if the host is not set)
std::string curl_hosts = "website.com:443:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
std::string curl_hosts80 = "website.com:80:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
host = curl_slist_append(host,curl_hosts.c_str());
host = curl_slist_append(host,curl_hosts80.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the host/ip to your [/etc/hosts](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec95.html) file

Comment: will do that also, but would defining it from curl's options be faster?

Comment: @SteveDell you *can* curl the ip directly. The diff between using the IP and letting the OS resolve the host to IP is meaningless.

Comment: I thought that because I was defining host: website.com in the header then curl may try to resolve that

Comment: @SteveDell it *will* try to resolve it but the resolving will be done at the OS level without making any network calls - that's why using /etc/hosts to link the host to the IP should be the same as curling the IP directly.